# Twitter-bootstrap add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, the code converts a large select list with optgroups into a more user-friendly tabbed Twitter-bootstrap component.

I'm not sure how much into detail I need to get but on GitHub I uploaded a [working example](https://github.com/alphacss/bootstrap-tabbed-select). This is the first time I write a jquery plugin and any advise is welcome.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bootstrapSelect = function(options) {

        //Extend default options with those provided.
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.bootstrapSelect.defaults, options);

        var topLevel='';
        var subLevel='';
        var selectedValue ='';
        var sectionActive = false;
        var selected = '';

        // Rewrite the info in the select box 
        $('optgroup',this).each(function(x) { //for each optgroup

            //get section label
            var sectionLabel = $(this).attr('label');

            //get section content
            var sectionContent = '';
            $('option',this).each(function(x) {

                /*Check if an option is selected, and set section active*/
                if ($(this).attr('selected')) {
                    selectedValue = $(this).attr('value');
                    sectionActive = true;
                }
                sectionContent += '<a ';
                $(this).attr('selected') ? sectionContent += 'class="bsactive" ' : '';
                sectionContent += 'value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>\n';
            });

            sectionActive ? selected = true : false;

            topLevel += '<li';
            sectionActive ? topLevel += ' class="active"' : '';
            topLevel += '><a href="#optgroup' + x + '" data-toggle="tab">' + sectionLabel + '</a></li>\n';

            subLevel += '<div id="optgroup' + x + '" class="tab-pane';
            sectionActive ? subLevel += ' active' : '';
            subLevel += '">\n' + sectionContent + '</div>\n';

            sectionActive = false;

        });
        //Replacement tabbed select
        var tabbedselect = '<div class="tabbable '+opts.position+'">\n';
        if ( opts.position != "tabs-below") tabbedselect += '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">\n'+topLevel+'</ul>\n';
        tabbedselect += '<div class="tab-content">\n'+subLevel+'</div>\n'
        if ( opts.position == "tabs-below") tabbedselect += '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">\n'+topLevel+'</ul>\n';
        tabbedselect += '</div>\n';

        // Replace the select with the tabbed menu
        this.replaceWith(tabbedselect);

        // Add hidden input field with the selected value
        $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="'+opts.inputId+'" id="'+opts.inputId+'" value="'+selectedValue+'" />');

        //set first tab and content area active if nothing is selected
        if (selected == false) {
            $("div.tab-content div:first-child").addClass("active");
            $("ul.nav-tabs li:first-child").addClass("active");
        }

        // set input field value on click
        $(".tab-content a").click(function () {
            $("*").removeClass("bsactive");
            $(this).addClass("bsactive");       
            $('input#'+opts.inputId).attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
        })
    };

    //default settings
    $.fn.bootstrapSelect.defaults = {
        'position' : 'tabs-left',
        'inputId'  : 'bootstrap-select'
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I set up a working example at http://tinker.io/fce06, would you please take a look an make sure that it looks and works as you would expect? It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use this plugin on a page with multiple forms, I would recommend identifying the specific form that you are operating on. I can see that you are aware of the issue because you have been using the context parameter in most of the selectors, but since the `<form>` is an ancestor of `this`, it would need to be selected differently:

```
$("form").append(...
```

should be

```
$(this).ancestor('form').append(...
```

Also, I just wanted to mention a personal preference when working with HTML snippets generated by jQuery. Instead of having HTML in JS strings, like

```
$(this).ancestor("form").append(
    '<input type="hidden" name="'+opts.inputId+'" id="'+opts.inputId+'" value="'+selectedValue+'" />'
);
```

I like to make hidden template elements, and then clone them, remove the `.template` class, set the attributes and inner html, and insert the clone into the document. For example:

```
// stylesheet:
.template { display: none; }

// html, near the end of the <body>:
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputTemplate" class="template"/>

// js:
$(this).ancestor('form').append(
    $('#hiddenInputTemplate')
    .clone()
    .removeClass('template')
    .attr('name', opts.inputId)
    .attr('id', opts.inputId)
    .val(selectedValue)
);
```

For a short example like this, it might not be worth the extra verbosity, but I do have reasons for doing it this way:

- My editor can't highlight HTML code, and especially syntax errors, inside of JS strings.
- I can read and understand this style a little faster, and I will read it more often than I will write it. Like I said, it's just personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the review.  I tried using "ancestor" but it didn't work, so I tried to see the documentation for it but didn't find it. I found "parents" which I believe does what was intended, the problem is that doesn't work either.
I believe it is because I do a "replaceWith" right before, so the object doesn't exist anymore. As a workaround I added the input field to the tabbedselect variable.
I also made other changes to support multiple instances.

Comment: Would it work to select the form and keep the selection in a variable, before doing the `replaceWith`? You would still be doing `form.append(...` after `replaceWith`.